# apt-get update on private IPv6 AWS EC2

Tags: networking, apt, amazon-ec2, ipv6

I have an EC2 on a private subnet with an IPv6 egress-only gateway. The VPC, subnet and EC2 all have IPv6 support and the EC2 has an IPv6 IP address assigned.

I can ping and run curl to pull down content from the internet.

However, when I run `apt-get update` I timeout:

```
root@ip-10-0-20-20:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:2 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease  Could not connect to us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.191.70.203), connection timed out
```

I'm assuming this is because it has a private IPv4 address (10.0.0.0/16) and is trying to use this to update? How do I get apt to run under IPv6? Why doesn't it try to connect archive.ubuntu.com via an IPv6 address?

If I try to force IPv6 I get `No address associated with hostname`, does this mean Ubuntu EC2 packages don't support IPv6??!!

```
root@ip-10-0-20-20:/var/snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566# sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv6=true update
Err:1 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the ec2 package repository mirror doesn't support IPv6.

After running the following to update `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use archive.ubuntu.com instead it ran fine with IPv6.

`sudo sed -i 's/us-west-2\.ec2\.//g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

You'll need to change the command to your specific region (us-east-1, etc.)

Comment: for some reason when i try`sudo apt -o Acquire::ForceIPv6=true update`, it looks like it actually resolves but then times out, as if it is a sg or route table issue.   I'm attempting egress only ::/0 with no ipv4 gateway. Maybe it's the same issue. `Could not connect to us-west-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com:80 (64:ff9b::d38:9674), connection timed out` Also notice the different sources, probably for arm64